# Can the Google Chrome preview link be moved to the bottom-right of the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, preview

I want to move the gray preview link from the bottom-left (default) to the bottom-right. Is this possible, either through an extension, Chrome Flags, or some other form of wizardry?